# IE Back Button issue in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i am having 2 jsp pages  test1.jsp and test2.jsp on test1.jsp i am posting some data and it will redirected to test2.jsp . but from test2.jsp if i clicked ie browser back button then it is showing **Webpage has  Expired** page so how shall i proceed to show test1.jsp on back button click? i am getting this issue in IE browser.

Answer (score 2):

Thus, you're actually not redirecting the request, but just `POST`ing (and forwarding) the request. You will namely get this error page whenever you tries to get a non-cached `POST` request from the browser history.

You need to *actually* **redirect** the request *after* `POST`. This is called the [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Assuming that your webapplication is well designed and that you're using a `Servlet` to control, preprocess and postprocess requests, then all you need to do is to invoke `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()` instead of `RequestDispatcher#forward()`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Postprocess request parameters here.

    // Finally redirect POST request to a brand new GET request.
    response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
}
```

This way the `POST` request won't be taken in the browser history. Pressing the back button will not get the `POST` request anymore, but the request which was invoked *before* it (i.e. the request used to open/view the page with the form).

The only caveat is that the initial request, including all of its parameters and attributes will disappear as well so that you can't make use of them in the result page. If necessary, you can go around this by using the session scope or a querystring/pathinfo in the redirect URL.

This particular "problem" is by the way not MSIE specific. Other browsers will behave the same, they would however only give a bit different error/warning message. In the future, before explicitly pointing MSIE as the root cause, please test with different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Redirect After Post](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=RedirectAfterPost) pattern.